# Ошибка при подключении к SQL Server: SQLServerException: Соединение закрыто

Tags: java, sql-server

Есть класс:

```
class Z {

    Connection conn = null;

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://XXX:1433;" +
                                                    "databaseName=cik;user=XXX;integratedSecurity=true;");
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public X Fun1(String p1) throws SQLException, IOException {
        X x1 = new X();
        try (Connection conn1 = getConnection()) {
            Statement stat = conn1.createStatement();
            try (ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("Exec MyFun1 @param1 = " + p1)) {
                if (result.next()) {
                    x1.setX(result.getString(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Fun1: "+e);
        }
        return x1;
    }

    public String Save(String p1, String p2) throws Exception {
        ...
        String res = "";
        X x1 = Fun1(p1);
        try (Connection conn2 = getConnection()) { // <== Вот тут исключение и появляется
            Statement stat1 = conn2.createStatement();
            try (ResultSet result1 = stat1.executeQuery("Exec MyFun2 @p1 = "+p1)) {
                while (result1.next()) {
                    ...
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Exec MyFun2: " + e);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Conn2: " + e);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

при вызове Save выдаёт Exception:

```
Conn2: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Соединение закрыто.
```

Почему? Что я делаю не так?
В этом же коде вызов:

```
X x1 = Fun1(p1);
```

отрабатывает нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Конструкция `try-with-resources` закрывает соединение по завершении работы:

```
try (Connection conn1 = getConnection()) {
    ...
} //по завершении блока try соединение будет закрыто.
```

Соответственно, при вызове `Fun1` создается соединение `conn`, выполняется запрос, после чего соединение закрывается. Далее идет обращение к закрытому соединению, о чем и говорит ошибка.

Варианты решения:

- Создавать для каждого запроса новое соединение и не сохранять его в `conn`.

  ```
  private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
      return DriverManager.getConnection("...");
  }
  ```
- Переиспользовать соединение для нескольких запросов — в этом случае не нужно оборачивать его в `try`:

  ```
  Connection conn1 = getConnection();
  Statement ...
  ```

  Также понадобится самому предусмотреть закрытие соединения после завершения работы с ним.